# Simplify the sum of vectorspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Consider the two subspaces $U_1,U_2\subset\mathbb{R}⁴$ given as $$U_1=\mathbb{R}(0,1,2,0)+\mathbb{R} (0,0,1,1),\quad U_2=\mathbb{R}(1,0,1,1)+\mathbb{R}(-3,1,1,-1).$$

How can I find vectors $w_1,w_2,w_3\in\mathbb{R}⁴$ such that $U_1+U_2=\mathbb{R}w_1+\mathbb{R}w_2+\mathbb{R}w_3$? I already found an vector $v$ such that $U_1\cap U_2=\mathbb{R}v$, namely $v=(0,1,4,2)$. Maybe this helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course it helps (if it is correct; I did not check it)! Call $w_3$ to your vector $v$. Find a vector $w_1\in U_1\setminus\mathbb{R}w_3$ and a vector $w_2\in U_2\setminus\mathbb{R}w_3$ and you're done.

Comment: Thank you! Why does this suffieces?

Comment: Because $U_1$ and $U_2$ have dimension $2$. Therefore $\{w_1,w_3\}$ is a basis of $U_1$ and $\{w_2,w_3\}$ is a basis of $U_2$. Therefore, $\{w_1,w_2,w_3\}$ spans $U_1+U_2$.

Answer (score 0):

Let call $v_1=(0,1,2,0),\ v_2=(0,0,1,1),\ v_3=(1,0,1,1),\ v_4=(-3,1,1,-1)$

You have $\DeclareMathOperator{\Span}{Span} U_1=\Span(v_1,v_2)$ and $U_2=\Span(v_3,v_4)$.

Since $a.v_1+b.v_2=0\iff\begin{cases}0=0\\a=0\\a+2b=0\\b=0\end{cases}\iff a=b=0\quad$ then $\dim U_1=2$.

Similarly $a.v_3+b.v_4=0\iff\begin{cases}a-3b=0\\b=0\\a+b=0\\a-b=0\end{cases}\iff a=b=0\quad$ then $\dim U_2=2$.

Now $U_1+U_2=\Span(v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4)$ but what is its dimension ?

$\sum a_iv_i=0\iff\begin{cases}c-3d=0\\a+d=0\\2a+b+c+d=0\\b+c-d=0\end{cases}\iff\begin{cases}c=3d\\a=-d\\0=0\\b=-2d\end{cases}$

This system is of dimension $1$ meaning that **$U_1+U_2$ is only of dimension $3$**.

This is because the $4$ vectors are not linearly independent : indeed $v_4=v_1+2v_2-3v_3$.

So finally a basis for $U_1+U_2$ is $\Span(v_1,v_2,v_3)$ but you can also select any $3$ among the $4$ vectors.

There was no need to go for $v\in U_1\cap U_2$ because you already have the vectors you want.

This would matter if you were asked for a basis of $V=U_1\cap U_2$ in order to find $E=V\oplus W$ where $V=\mathbb Rv=\Span(w_3)$ and $W=\Span(w_1,w_2)$.

But here you are NOT asked for a direct sum, just $U_1+U_2$, this is a simpler question, and the resulting basis is just a subset of the set of vectors forming the basis for $U_1$ and $U_2$.

Comment: So just because $v_4$ is a linear combination of the others we have that $v_1,v_2,v_3$ span $U_1+U_2$, right? There is no more argument needed?

Comment: yes, because $av_1+bv_2+cv_3=0$ is the same as setting $d=0$ so we get $a=b=c=0$ and $v_1,v_2,v_3$ are linearly independent, so it is a basis of $U_1+U_2$.

Comment: Yes but we don't need that basis argument since we just want to find three spanning vectors.